# Apache not serving css files larger than 2KB

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mediatemple

I have uploaded 2 css files to my document root

- http://sastobook.com/small.css
- http://sastobook.com/big.css

small.css is less than 2KB and big.css is larger than 2KB.

The big.css does not get served no matter what I do.

The same goes  for image files too.

All files are setup on a VPS.
VHost Settings are as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/public/"
ServerName myproject
   <Directory "/path/to/my/public/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name matches 100%? Remember that Linux' filesystems are usually case sensitive.

Comment: What does the Apache error log say?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have no error in my logs. 
When i move the document root one step up it works fine

Comment: A 404 error will always create an entry in the error log. It must be somewhere.

Comment: you shud check the file permissions provided to big.css. also i think you got cache mgmt tool nginx running there.. check its log if available.

Comment: @Pekka웃
There are no errors pertaining to big.css. Just checked my logs. If you run " curl -I http://sastobook.com/big.css " then status 200 OK should come.

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha makes a good point: it's Nginx complaining about the missing file. Weird. Can you check out Nginx's error logs?

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha file permissions are ok. I think its a problem with nginx file path. The vhost configuration for apache needs a similar change in file path withing nginx configuration. Will check.

Nginx log: open(): "/path/to/file/big.css" failed
Apache Log: no error

Comment: soden @Pekka웃 gudluck ;)